# MongoDB Match Negative All

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xyx8XlqtlOp)

Lets say I have docs with 3 props, FieldA, B, C.

I would like to do a match of all docs that don´t have the 3 props null.

I am trying $all, $nor, $not, $ne, etc... but none are working.

Ex.

```
[
  { "FieldA": 1, "FieldB": 1, "FieldC": 1,},              //1
  { "FieldA": 1, "FieldB": null, "FieldC": null,},        //2
  { "FieldA": null, "FieldB": 1, "FieldC": null,},        //3
  { "FieldA": null, "FieldB": null, "FieldC": 1,},        //4
  { "FieldA": null, "FieldB": null, "FieldC": null,},     //5
]
```

In my aggregation, I need to match all from 1st to 4th, but not 5th.

Get only the 5th is easy, but I need the negative of that.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$or": [
          {
            "$ne": [
              "$FieldA",
              null
            ]
          },
          {
            "$ne": [
              "$FieldB",
              null
            ]
          },
          {
            "$ne": [
              "$FieldC",
              null
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R-KCqHi46ri)

Comment: This works fine... but if I want to do in de negative way (ex. I dont want any doc that has these 3 props null)... how would be?

Comment: You mean to exclude the docs if at least one field is `null`?

Comment: exclude if all 3 are null..

Comment: You can do it like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/4yE3PhdzMNB

Answer (score 0):

The `not` operator takes only one argument expression. [Link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#boolean-expression-operators)

You can try instead using an `and`/`or` operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "FieldA": {
            "$ne": null
          }
        },
        {
          "FieldB": {
            "$ne": null
          }
        },
        {
          "FieldC": {
            "$ne": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```